# Integración Ionic con ePayco

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, ionic, sdk

tengo que enlazar la pasarela de pagos [ePayco](https://epayco.co/) a mi aplicación en Ionic. Según la [documentación](https://docs.epayco.co/tools/split-payment) puedo usar el SDK de Node. Instale por npm el SDK y lo importé en una página de la aplicación.

```
import * as epaycoNode from 'epayco-sdk-node';
```

En el método para pagar declare la variable según la documentación.

```
var epayco = epaycoNode({
    apiKey: 'PUBLIC_KEY',
    privateKey: 'PRIVATE_KEY',
    lang: 'ES',
    test: true
})
```

Cuando intenté correr en el dispositivo tuve un error relacionado con con global el cual solucioné con

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

Despues intenté de nuevo en el dispositivo y tengo el error
"err: TypeError: os.networkInterfaces is not a function"
No he podido solucionar este error. Alguien me puede colaborar?

Comment: Estas intentando importar y usar epayco directamente en una pagina de la aplicacion segun dices, recuerda que nodejs corre del lado del servidor y pues... estas intentando usar algo que corre del lado del servidor en el cliente, tecnicamente no seria lo mismo renderizar el archivo con node que renderizarlo con ionic directamente haciendo uso del sdk instalado, puesto que node interpreta javascript diferente que ionic...

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Es decir que no puedo realizar esa integración?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui se encuentra ionic:

```
cliente

ionic
```

Aqui se encuentra nodejs:

```
servidor

nodejs
```

Como se verían juntos:

```
cliente ---------------------------------  servidor

ionic   ---------------------------------  nodejs
```

Aquello que intentas en pseudocodigo:

```
importar epayco in ionic;
usar epayco in ionic();
```

Aquello que debes enrealidad hacer:

```
import epayco in nodejs;
usar epayco in nodejs();
```

Recordemos que nodejs corre del lado del servidor, por lo que para poder usar esta información se hace por medio de una petición `POST` a nuestro servidor de epayco montado en nodejs, para luego reenviar una respuesta al cliente (ionic), para poder nosotros hacer una u otra cosa de acuerdo a lo que haya ocurrido por parte de node, en este caso la peticion `POST` es para llevar los datos del pago hacia `nodejs` y que desde `node` se pueda hacer la transacción, y en el cliente (ionic) darnos cuenta de aquello que ocurrio.

Es por esto que no funciona, porque intentas usar javascript como si fuese nodejs dentro de ionic, lo cual por muchas partes va a dar errores... debido a por ejemplo:

- Nodejs corre del lado del servidor, no del cliente, ionic corre del lado del cliente.
- Ionic al final al compilar lo lleva todo o casi todo a `java`, y cosas no nativas de este posiblemente las interprete mal, como por ejemplo tener que reemplazar la instancia de la ventana:

`(window as any).global = window;`

- Recursos que solo posee nodejs (no estan en javascript puro) por lo que no pueden ser usados en `ionic`, a menos de que tengas instalado `nodejs` en `ionic` lo cual no tiene sentido... de hecho hacerlo no es recomendable.

Comment: De hecho en la misma documentacion de epayco en cierta parte se menciona algo de POST con un boton de pago: https://docs.epayco.co/tools/split-payment

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias. Tendré que contactarme con el soporte para ver si me indican los enlaces y parametros para realizar las peticiones.

Comment: De nada amigo Nelson Hernandez, recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda, puedes darla como aceptada, me alegra haberte ayudado.